# why my website very slow can any one help me?

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce

I have VPS 2core 4GB ram
website is WordPress with WooCommerce and WCFM Multivendor
https://hdomz.com/wordpress/wp3

I tried testing the site
https://tools.pingdom.com/
And
https://pagespeed.web.dev/
But to no avail I have no idea why the site is so slow
There is no other site on this VPS
i want any one help me

Comment: stack overflow is related to coding problems… Try to search and ask in here: https://serverfault.com/search?q=wordpress+slow

Answer (score 0):

there can be many reasons why a page is very or too slow.

1. too many requests to the server, which can affect the speed
2. too many frameworks can throttle the speed
3. if too many objects should be loaded at the same time on the start page, this can also cause delayrn.
4. if the page is running on a web server and it is too slow, this can also lead to time delays.

Comment: (Load time 20.48 s) , (Requests 204) How can I find out the cause of the problem